# How to wait for the return of a Mongoose search?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, bluebird

I created a CRUD with NodeJS / Mongoose, split the files in MVC style. In route example I show up below, when the `retrieveOne` routine is executed, it's necessary to wait for its processing and then redirect the user to one route or another. I'd like to use Bluebird to wait for processing. I need some help to implement the routine.

Index.js -----------------------------------------------

```
const myCRUD = require('./api/controllers/controller')

router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {   

   // HOW TO IMPLEMENT BLUEBIRD HERE?

   // How to wait for the "retrieveOne" process and a then do a "if" test (below)?   
   let ret = myCRUD.retrieveOne({ name: "abc test" }); 


   if(!ret) {
      res.redirect('/success')
   } else {
      res.redirect('/error')
   }
})
```

controller.js ------------------------------------------

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = require('./schema-user');
const Model = mongoose.model('users', Schema);

const CRUD = {
   retrieveOne: function(query) {
      Model.findOne(query, function(err, result) {
         if (err) return err;
         return result;
      });
   }
}

module.exports = CRUD;
```

**Note**: I've already found several examples with and without Bluebird right here in S.O., but I couldn't get it to work:
Examples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33269384/how-to-wait-mongoose-exec-function-to-be-done), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180896/how-to-return-mongoose-results-from-the-find-method), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50454854/how-to-wait-for-mongoose-list-item-to-be-pushed), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54613321/wait-for-mongoose-to-resolve-data-before-returning), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606965/how-to-wait-for-the-result-of-a-mongoose-query)

Comment: As an aside, the query you are passing to retrieveOne looks a little wonky. Is that a typo? It should be something more like: `myCRUD.retrieveOne({ name: "abc test"});`

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's a typo. I've already fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `async` and `await`

```
const myCRUD = require('./api/controllers/controller')
const Promise = require('bluebird');

router.post('/login', async function(req, res, next) {   

   // HOW TO IMPLEMENT BLUEBIRD HERE?

   // How to wait for the "retrieveOne" process and a then do a "if" test (below)?   
   let ret = await myCRUD.retrieveOne('{ name: "abc test"'); 


   if(!ret) {
      res.redirect('/success')
   } else {
      res.redirect('/error')
   }
})

// controller.js ------------------------------------------

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = require('./schema-user');
const Model = mongoose.model('users', Schema);

const CRUD = {
   retrieveOne: function(query) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Model.findOne(query, function(err, result) {
           if (err) reject(err);
           resolve(result);
        });
      });
   }
}

module.exports = CRUD;
```

Comment: Although this method works really well with most functions that use callbacks, it's actually not necessary here, because Model.findOne returns a promise, so there's no need to use the callback at all.

Comment: As in the *djheru* response, it also shown the following error: `let ret = await myCRUD.retrieveOne('{ name: "abc test"');` error `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`. I made some modifications and get to make it work partially, but I couldn't get back `result` nor `err`. :(

Comment: If it is modified to this way, it works: `myCRUD.create(myQuery).then((result) => { console.log(result); }).catch((err) => { console.log(err); })`. Also, It must remove this `let ret = await` from line of function `myCRUD.retrieve`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need to use Bluebird for this, as mongoose works just fine with native Promises

In your controller:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = require('./schema-user');
const Model = mongoose.model('users', Schema);

const CRUD = {
   retrieveOne: function(query) {
      // findOne() returns a Promise ()
      // https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
      return Model.findOne(query);
   }
}

module.exports = CRUD;
```

Now, you can make your route handler an `async` function and just `await` the Promise

```
const myCRUD = require('./api/controllers/controller')

router.post('/login', async function(req, res, next) { 
   let ret = await myCRUD.retrieveOne({ name: "abc test"}); 
   if(!ret) {
      res.redirect('/success')
   } else {
      res.redirect('/error')
   }
})
```

Comment: I'm newbie to NodeJS and I think I keep doing something wrong. I made a copy and paste of your code, so It was presented the following error: `let ret = await myCRUD.retrieveOne(msgJSON);` error: `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`. Can you help me one more time? thanks!

Comment: Yep, you have to add `async` right before the function keyword

`router.post('/login', async function(req, res, next) {`

Comment: Really .... I suppose I'd never see this `async` in the `post` line if you didn't show me it. Now it works! Thank you.